# ggplot force axes to start with 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

In a line plot (with ggplot + geom_line)
is there a way to force axes to start at 0?
Of course it can be done by computing the maximum and then using
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max)) but I think this is needed often enough to deserve an option of its own.
Can it be done without explicitly giving the maximum?

Comment: Yes just use `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, NA))` to have the `NA` replaced by the natural maximum.

Comment: Nice trick.  I did not know this.